# Blocking a contractor's access to the internal machines when remote desktop'ing in

Tags: firewall, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have a VOIP contractor that's going to need remote access to a server on our network, and it's not on a separate vlan.  I'm sure he'll need some access to the public world to do his work, but I would like to block his access to the internal network. Think that'd be in the manual or would the better solution not even involve ZT directly?  Maybe some firewall rules that block traffic to the internal LANs (a local netblock & a VPN-connected netblock in another city).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you install zerotier only on your server, the contractor will be able to reach only your server via the zerotier net.
Keep in mind that when connected, from your server he will be able to see your internal lan...
This is not a zerotier problem, you should put your server in a dmz...